# Is it possible to change a page given its URL?

Tags: javascript, html5

I have an HTML page.  There is a link to another page.  When I load this other page, it has a header which I do not want to appear.  I do not have access to edit the source code for the existing HTML.  Is there a way I can hide an element from a URL without changing the code directly?

For example, can I load webmasters.stackexchange.com without having the black navbar at the top being shown?

Another example, can I open [A very simple webpage](http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/pages/sykes_webdesign/05_simple.html) without the top header (`<h1>A very simple webpage. This is an "h1" level header.</h1>`) being shown?  If so, how?

I am hoping to keep this in a simple JavaScript, but I have had no luck googling this answer.  This is presenting me some difficulty since I cannot edit the html file directly.

Comment: Without source code access you can not do anything..

Comment: Are you wanting this to be public to everyone or only visible (or not) to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iframe to load target website in another html page. You need to change the link in the first page though and create a second html with iframe for the target website. You can show a portion of the target website using css.

However, if you don't own the target website, it may be illegal. Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009815/iframes-and-law